# How can I join two tables when there an ID is repeated multiple times?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the table structure:

Table 1

```
tid ts1

u1 t1
u1 t2
u1 t3
```

Table 2

```
tid ts2

u1 ta1
u1 ta2
u1 ta3
```

I want a table such that:

```
tid ts1 ts2

u1 t1 ta1
u1 t2 ta2
u1 t3 ta3
```

Both tables are ordered by ts columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better description what's decided and the ofcolumns and wider range of possible values may produce a better answer. One way for the given problem:

```
select t1.tid, t1.ts1, t2.ts2
  from tablel1 t1
  join table2  t2 
    on (t1.tid = t2.tid)
 where t1.ts1 = regexp_replace(ts2,'^(.).(.)','\1\2') ;
```